# How to use event and variables in the same function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```js
function edit(id) {
    
    let name = document.querySelector('#name');
    let price = document.querySelector('#price');


    name.value = products[id].name;
    price.value = products[id].price;
    
    document.querySelector(".update").addEventListener('click', update('e',id));
    
}


function update(e,id) {
    
    e.preventDefault;
    
    let name = document.querySelector('#name');
    let price = document.querySelector('#price');
    
    products[id].name = name.value;
    products[id].price = price.value;
    
    showProduct();
    
}
```

I want to use `preventDefault` in the function, but I could not fix that.

```
 document.querySelector(".update").addEventListener('click', update('e',id));
```

In this line I send `'e'` for the event. In the update function I'm using like this:

```
e.preventDefault;
```

But its not working. How can I fix this problem. If you help me I will be glad.

Comment: Have tried using "this" instead of "e". like this addEventListener('click', update(this,id));

Comment: `.addEventListener('click', e=>update(e,id))`

Comment: 'e' is just a string not an `event`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are sending the event as a string.

change this :

```
function edit(id) {
    
    let name = document.querySelector('#name');
    let price = document.querySelector('#price');


    name.value = products[id].name;
    price.value = products[id].price;
    
    // change
    document.querySelector(".update").addEventListener('click', e => {
      update(e,id)
    });    
}
```